# Merge feature data rows of a shapefile

Tags: c#, sharpmap, dotspatial, nettopologysuite

I'm using `NetTopologySuite` to read a shapefile like below code:

```
        private FeatureDataTable GetFeatureTableFromShapefile(string shapeFilePath)
    {
        GeoAPI.GeometryServiceProvider.Instance = new NetTopologySuite.NtsGeometryServices();
        FeatureDataSet ds;
        using (var sf = new ShapeFile(shapeFilePath) {Encoding = Encoding.Default})
        {
            sf.Open();
            var ext = sf.GetExtents();
            ds = new FeatureDataSet();
            sf.ExecuteIntersectionQuery(ext, ds);
        }

        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
```

Now I want to merge all features (`GeoMetry`) and create only one feature from them.

Please note that I'm trying to create one feature and not something like multipolygon like below image:
[image]

For above image, i used this code, but it's not what i want, because there still a red line between to features that i tried to merge:

```
            var entities = new List<DbGeometry>(){ d1.Geom, d2.Geom};
        DbGeometry allBoundaries = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < entities.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0) allBoundaries = entities[i].Boundary;
            else allBoundaries = allBoundaries.Union(entities[i].Boundary);
        }
```

So is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a tool similar to Dissolve in ArcGIS.

Comment: @smiller That's right. something like that but programatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem with such a merge is that the polygons' vertices might not be perfectly aligned. It consists of floats that will have small differences. Not sure if there is a perfect solution here.

One workaround is to grow the polygons with a tiny buffer, then union, and then shrink with that same buffer.

Another solution is to snap your points to a grid before Union. I think NTS's SnappedUnion does this

```
else allBoundaries = allBoundaries.SnappedUnion(entities[i].Boundary, 0.0001);
```

Comment: oh, and you could also go all fancy and represent your data topological. Meaning the adjacent geometries have a reference to one and the same vertex on their shared border. I guess this is actually the proper solution, but not easy.

Comment: Your link refer to sql server solution, Is there any c# code for that.

Comment: I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, Now i can do what i wanted, but the code i'm using is this: `NetTopologySuite.Operation.Overlay.Snap.SnapOverlayOp.Union`